# Azure Ubuntu Zimbra rDNS Spam Issues

Tags: azure

Does Azure support rDNS? If so, I need to contact Microsoft about getting my Azure IP -> domain.

I heard somewhere that Azure does NOT support Reverse DNS. My SPF records are fine.

Answer (score 0):

it does: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/

> You can add reverse DNS to an existing Cloud Service using the
>   “Set-AzureService” cmdlet:

```
PS C:\> Set-AzureService –ServiceName “contosoapp1” –Description “App1
 with Reverse DNS” –ReverseDnsFqdn “contosoapp1.cloudapp.net.”
```